# Text underline that colide with an image

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, underline

I'm using bootstrap library in a project and I want to make the underline of the h1 "meet" the picture, just like in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aajZI.jpg . What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: Show us what *you* have done so far, please.

Comment: use something like jsfiddle.net to build a demo and link to it, and post some coed so we can at least see what you're trying.

Comment: I would suggest not doing this with `text-decoration:underline` on your `h1`. Instead I would either use a `<hr />` or a 1px height `div`. That way you should have greater control over the spacing top and bottom of the line

Comment: This is what I've coded so far: http://imgur.com/8LQs7TX

Comment: We need to see code, but good job it looks nice (and not to much like bootstrap which is kind of impressive)

Comment: And here is the relevant code: http://jsfiddle.net/M8F5t/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a div element with a small height and a background colour that has an absolute position on the page relative to the image.

Comment: But this div will be after the h1 and before the img. I don't want that. I want the underline to be on the same line as the image.

Comment: @Milo you can use absolute or fixed positioning to position it inside the photo

Comment: I've made it. The solution is so simple, but I didn't though about it. Thank you! http://imgur.com/WkGCN1Y

Comment: i don't have enough reputation for that